# In Java springdata, i can't add uuid into sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

it is query code.

```
@Query(value = "select * from lb.relationship where serverid=?1 and serviceid=?2 and port=?3", nativeQuery = true)
VipServiceToServerRelationship findByServerIdAndServiceIdAndPort(UUID svrId, UUID svcId, String port);
```

it is schema.

```
CREATE TABLE lb.relationship (
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    serverid uuid NOT NULL,
    serviceid uuid NOT NULL,
    port character varying NOT NULL
);
```

I try the cmd below directly in pg's console and get the right anwser

```
select * from lb.relationship  where serverid=('d5dd2a02-960b-4c7b-ad9c-92e3650ab763'::uuid) and serviceid=('83265e81-7e14-4ff0-a4cc-6228a0d25f0d'::uuid) and port='80'
or
select * from lb.relationship  where serverid='d5dd2a02-960b-4c7b-ad9c-92e3650ab763' and serviceid='83265e81-7e14-4ff0-a4cc-6228a0d25f0d' and port='80'
```

> **Error message:**
>
> operator does not exist: uuid = bytea

From other similar questions' answer, I still can't figure out my failure.
I don't have extra " " or ";" in my sql.

---

**Update**

I try to run springdata directly which get the same failure.

> ** Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = bytea Hint: No operator matches the given name and
>   argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. **

– 徐松峰 12 hours ago

---

**Solution**

Once i modify the schema from uuid to string, everything is fixed

– 徐松峰 11 hours ago

Comment: ```operator does not exist: uuid = bytea```
it is the error msg

Comment: 1) One of the most important things to put in your post: *THE EXACT ERROR MESSAGE*.  I took the liberty of doing this for you.  2) Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19751613/3135317

Comment: @FoggyDay So how do you know this is the actual error message? The referenced question only deals with JDBC while the OP uses JPA.

Comment: thx, FoggyDay.
I think the method of query is different between this case and the case in that issue.
I have hard code the type uuid in the params which should be transported to the query cmd above the function.

Comment: hi Jens Schauder, this error msg showed on my intelJ when i run that function

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674556/operator-does-not-exist-uuid-bytea-java-with-postgres

Comment: I try to run springdata directly which get the same failure.
**
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = bytea
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
**

Comment: Once i modify the schema from uuid to string, everything is fixed

Answer (score 1):

Q: Have you tried an explicit type cast?

EXAMPLE:

```
@Query(value = "select * from lb.relationship where serverid=CAST(?1 AS uuid) and serviceid=CAST(?2 AS uuid) and port=?3", nativeQuery = true)
```